# How to set missing X-Robots-Tag for HTTP 301 response?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, redirect, x-robots-tag

I want to set noindex x-robots tag for a particular bad search engine which index even redirect page, instead of final destination.

At the top of my root .htaccess file, I have added below rules.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header add X-Robots-Tag "BadBot: noindex"
</IfModule>
```

It works this way.

```
Requesting http://example.com/page

SERVER RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

Date: Mon, 17 Jul 2017 11:17:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.com/page


SERVER RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

Date: Mon, 17 Jul 2017 11:17:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.example.com/page/
X-Robots-Tag: BadBot: noindex


SERVER RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Mon, 17 Jul 2017 11:17:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Robots-Tag: BadBot: noindex
```

Requested: `http://example.com/page` 
Final: `https://www.example.com/page/`

In the requested URL, the **X-robots-tag** is missing while forcing HTTPS. Is there any way tackle this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Rather confusingly, the question is also tagged `nginx`? It would have been useful to have seen where/how the redirects are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Header add X-Robots-Tag "BadBot: noindex"
> ```

As posted this directive would not have set the header on either of the 301 redirects. It would have only set the header on the final 200 OK response.

*Aside:* In order to analyse why you were seeing the header on one of the 301 redirects we would need to see where/how the redirects were implemented and whether you have other code that could be setting this header. It looks like there is something else going on.

The default *condition* for the `header` directive is `onsuccess`, which means the header is only set on 2xx responses. To set the header on all responses, including 3xx (redirects) and 4xx (not found) then you need to use the `always` *condition*.

For example:

```
Header always set X-Robots-Tag "BadBot: noindex"
```

*Aside:* No need to use `add` here; `set` is preferable, since you only want to set this header once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a small syntax error. Instead of `Header add X-Robots-Tag` it should be `Header set X-Robots-Tag`

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Robots-Tag "BadBot: noindex"
</IfModule>
```

Reference  :  https://yoast.com/x-robots-tag-play/

Comment: Whether you use `add` or `set` here should not be significant. Strictly speaking, it should be `set` just because you only want the header to be set once. In theory, using `add` could result in the header being set more than once. (But the issue here is that it's not being set at all.)